# Hive - Count number of occurrences of character

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to count number of occurrences of pipe symbol in Hive - (6)

```
select length(regexp_replace('220138|251965797?AIRFR?150350161961|||||','^(?:[^|]*\\|)(\\|)','')) from smartmatching limit 10
```

This is what I am trying and I am not getting it right.

Comment: you can replace anything other than `|` with `''` this regex :- `[^|]` and then count the number of characters

Answer (score 11):

This will work

```
SELECT LENGTH(regexp_replace('220138|251965797?AIRFR?150350161961|||||','[^|]',''))
```